# Bootloader won't load any commands

Tags: bootloader

My Bootloader won't do anything, when I type fastboot getvar all it stops giving the strings half way, or when typing any other command it will only give ... and nothing more. Bootloader log only shows: cmd: oem-info and nothing more

Comment: check cable+jack (loose or broken)

Comment: I already tried different ports and pcs. Cable is fine too. It is detected in computer in both fastboot and adb state. Is there any way to check for bootloader logs in a more advanced way?( Too see if it shows any errors) The default only shows me my commands

Comment: must be the cable or port related. maybe COM transfer rate (SuperSpeed) is too high. Do you use latest version? https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads

Comment: Yes I do use latest version, thanks. Idk what this COM transfer rate is...

Comment: connect intermediate usb 2.0 hub to eliminate speed problems

Comment: Hi, looks like you've found the solution with the help of someone, which is great! Instead of posting an answer that looks like a comment (it's technically "not an answer" and will get deleted), consider writing a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed, but even encouraged!](//android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) Otherwise, you might want to ask them to post a proper answer for you instead. Thanks!